# Is it available to start JMeter remotely on several (more than 2) Linux servers from one Windows server?

Tags: linux, jmeter, distributed-testing

Is it available to start JMeter on several (more than 2) Linux servers? JMeter on Linux servers are contolled by JMeter on Windows. I know that there is an ability to start JMeter remotely on one Linux server http://blog.ionelmc.ro/2012/02/16/how-to-run-jmeter-over-ssh-tunnel/. What about several Linux servers?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following document for setting up jmeter in distributed environment.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

1. Setup jmeter on 2 linux machines and start
   bin/jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=
2. Setup jmeter on windows server as controller
   bin/jmeter.properties
   edit the line “remote_hosts=127.0.0.1”
   add the IP address. For example,remote_hosts=192.168.0.10,192.168.0.11,192.168.0.12
3. Start jmeter.bat on windows controller

hope this will help